# giving a class instance the name of a variable

Tags: c#, class, naming

How can i give a class instance the name of an existing variable. I am trying like this `string hex = "BF43F";  Zeugh hex = new Zeugh();` but its wrong. I want to create an object BF43F with the properties of Zeugh class.

Comment: Instances don't have names, in general.

Comment: @jayt csharp: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Why does it matter whether the variable is named `BF43F`?

Comment: BF43F is the id and the name of the object i want to create. Each while cycle will give different values to hex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `Dictionary<string, Zeugh>`.  For example:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, Zeugh>();
string hex = "BF43F"; 
d.Add(hex, new Zeugh());
```

(later)

```
Zeugh it = d["BF43F"];
```

Comment: how can i refer to the object created with new Zeugh() in the dictionary?

Comment: @jayt: Like `d["BF43F"]` as illustrated in my answer (and a string variable can be used there as well).  If you want to know if a particular name exists, use `d.TryGetValue`.  To find all name/object pairs, use `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Zeugh> entry in d)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare two variables with the same name in the same scope.
If you later access the variable `hex`, how should the compiler know if you mean the "BF43F" string or the `Zeugh` object?

Or do you want an object with the same properties as a `Zeugh` object, but with one additional string property to save your string "BF43F" in?

You could create another class which inherits from `Zeugh` and has an additional string property:

```
public class ExtendedZeugh : Zeugh
{
    public string AdditionalString { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can store your string "BF43F" in this property:

```
var hex = new ExtendedZeugh();
hex.AdditionalString = "BF43F";
```

Comment: I think he wants to create a variable named BF43F of type Zeugh, but he will know the name to give to the variable (i.e. BF43F") only at runtime.

Comment: exactly this is the situation.

Comment: In this situation I would choose Ben Voigt's approach