# keeping variables aside from a while loop

Tags: c#, arrays, class, naming

I am receiving from a serial port (vhf receiver) some data from different sources lets say for example cars. The whole program at the moment is a while loop. While the port is open i am receiving bytes in arrays and do some decoding. Every cycle of the while loop 1 message is received and decoded. But in one case there is a message that is split in to parts an odd part and an even part. I need both to decode the message but only one part is received in 1 while cycle lets say the oddpart from **car1**. The next while cycle may contain oddpart from **car2** or evenpart from **car1** or evenpart from **car3** etc. So i need a way to store the odd even parts of each car until both of them are received. And another important thing: there should be a 10 seconds time window from the moment i receive the first part until the moment i recieve the second part. If 10seconds pass the first part should be descarded. I guess arrays wont work because i need something dynamic like a List or a dictionary.

```
while (serialportopen)
{
//somedecoding I end up with
string hexid;
string oddpart;
string evenpart;
}
```

I tried creating a class [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976156/giving-a-class-instance-the-name-of-a-variable) with properties to hold the message parts but i cant create an object with the name hexid because it is already declared. Any ideas including lists dictionaries or classes?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we have tags for on SO.

Comment: Please say why this is not a duplicate of your earlier question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976156/giving-a-class-instance-the-name-of-a-variable.

Comment: because its a different question

Comment: I meant, give some detail on why it's a different question. It's about the same situation, but what's different between the two?

Comment: This is about approaching the concept. The other is technical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you have a way to telle an odd part from an even part, from a complete id, and that you have a way to tell the origin of your message. In this case I would store the oddparts (if they are always the ones that are received first) in a dictionary. When I receive an even part I would check to see if there is its corresponding odd part stored and if this is the case I would process the whole thing, otherwise I would discard it. Furthermore, when I receive an odd part I would start a timer responsible for deleting it from the dictionary after 10 seconds are passed. Since the timer has to be stopped, it will be stored in a dictionary, too. Something like this (it's only an example, probably you'd want to create some instance variables to avoid passing parameters everywhere):

```
Dictionary<string, string> oddParts = new Dictionary>string, string>();
Dictionary<string, Timer> timers = new Dictionary<string, Timer>();
while (serialportopen)
{
    // somedecoding I end up with
    string hexid;
    string oddpart;
    string evenpart;
    // you need something to identify where the message came from and that is present in both the odd and even part (the BF... of your previous question)
    string msgId;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oddpart))
        ProcessOddPart(msgId, oddpart, oddParts, timers);
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(evenpart))
        hexid = HexIdFromEvenPart(msgId, evenpart, oddparts, timers);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hexid))
        Process(hexid);
}

void Process(string hexid)
{
    // your stuff here
}

void ProcessOddPart(string msgId, string oddPart, Dictionary<string, string> oddParts, Dictionary<string, Timer> timers)
{
    oddParts[msgId] = oddPart;
    System.Timers.Timer tmr = new Timer(); 
    timers[msgId = tmr;
    ElapsedEventHandler timePassed = delegate(object anObj, ElapsedEventArgs args) {
        tmr.Stop();
        oddParts.Remove(msgId);
        timers.Remove(msgId);
    };
    tmr.Interval = 10000;
    tmr.Elapsed += timePassed;
    tmr.Start();
}

void HexIdFromEvenPart(string msgId, string evenPart, Dictionary<string, string> oddParts, Dictionary<string, Timer> timers)
{
    string oddPart;
    Timer tmr;
    if (timers.TryGetValue(msgId, out tmr))
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        timers.Remove(msgId);
    }
    if (!oddParts.TryGetValue(msgId, out oddPart))
        return null;
    return oddPart + evenPart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way most systems do it, when dealing with variable length data segments, is there's something unique about the first packet that comes through, that notifies the receiving driver that it's two part.  For example, it might simply be the MSB (most significant bit) set or unset on the first packet, where 0 could denote that there is no second packet, and 1 could denote that there is a second packet.  Then it's simply a matter of masking it when y you get it, and calling a function to receive the second part, or setting a flag that the second part needs to be received, and that it's NOT a new packet.

As for the scope, I'm kind of foggy on what you're asking, but based on the code above, if you declare the variables outside the loop, ie.:

```
string hexid;
string oddpart;
string evenpart;
while (serialportopen)
{

}
```

They'll maintain scope for multiple iterations of the loop.  It's better to do it that way regardless, as it won't re-declare the variable each time.  That may or may not be optimized out by the compiler.

Otherwise there's something uniqe about the bit pattern of that packet that notifies the driver that another packet is needed.  There may be an opcode or command field in that packet, it may be simply an issue of masking that, calling on a function to retrieve and return the second part, ie.

```
if ((command & CERTAIN_PACKET) == CERTAIN_PACKET)
    odpart = GetSecondPart();
```

I hope that helps you some!